Flask App Works Locally But Fails to Deploy on Google Cloud Run: "Failed to Start and Listen on the Port"
Problem:
I'm trying to deploy a Flask app with a pre-trained machine learning model (stored as a model.pkl file in the same directory) to Google Cloud Run. The container runs perfectly fine locally, but fails when deploying to Cloud Run with the following error:
ERROR: (gcloud.run.deploy) Revision 'mymodel-service-00015-svm' is not ready and cannot serve traffic. The user-provided container failed to start and listen on the port defined provided by the PORT=8080 environment variable.
Commands I'm Using:

Building the Docker image:
docker build --no-cache -t gcr.io/dehaproject2024/mymodel:latest .

Pushing the Docker image:
docker push gcr.io/dehaproject2024/mymodel:latest

Deploying to Google Cloud Run:
gcloud run deploy mymodel-service \ --image gcr.io/dehaproject2024/mymodel:latest \ --platform managed \ --region me-west1 \ --allow-unauthenticated


The Project Structure:
.
├── server.py          # The Flask app file
├── Dockerfile         # The Dockerfile for building the container
├── model.pkl          # The ML model (pickle file)
├── requirements.txt   # Dependencies

server.py (Flask App):
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
import pandas as pd
import pickle
import os

app = Flask(__name__)

# Load your trained model (assuming it's a pickle file)
model = pickle.load(open('model.pkl', 'rb'))


@app.route('/predict', methods=['POST'])
def predict():
    try:
        json_data = request.get_json()  # Get data posted as JSON
        data = pd.DataFrame(json_data)  # Convert JSON to pandas DataFrame

        # Assuming your model expects the data in the same format as your training data
        # Make sure to handle preprocessing if needed
        predictions = model.predict(data)
        return jsonify(predictions.tolist())  # Return predictions as JSON
    except Exception as e:
        return jsonify({"error": str(e)}), 400


if __name__ == "__main__":
    port = int(os.environ.get("PORT", 8080))
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=port)

Dockerfile:
FROM python:3.10-slim

WORKDIR /app

COPY . /app

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 8080

ENV PORT 8080

CMD ["gunicorn", "--bind", "0.0.0.0:$PORT", "server:app"]

What I Tried:

The container works locally when I run it like this:
docker run -p 8080:8080 gcr.io/dehaproject2024/mymodel:latest

I have confirmed the app runs fine locally and responds to /predict endpoint.

I’ve tried making sure that the app is binding to the correct port by using $PORT environment variable, both in the server.py file and the Dockerfile.

I'm still getting the same error message as stated above.

the requirements.txt is up-to-date with all necessary dependencies.


What Could Be the Issue?

Does it work if you revise the CMD line to be CMD ["gunicorn", "--bind", "0.0.0.0:8080", "server:app"]? I think you don't get the variable substitution in the CMD.

Unfortunately, no, same error :/

I'm unable to repro your issue. The Cloud Run error is slightly misleading. You should focus on why the container isn't starting correctly. Please update your question with (a) the set of commands you're using to create the Cloud Run service; (b) the logs.


Remove EXPOSE 8080 and ENV PORT 8080(You're removing the latter because cloud run documentation says


In particular, the PORT environment variable is injected inside your container by Cloud Run. You should not set it yourself


Change the final line to CMD exec gunicorn --bind :$PORT server:app


It didn't work, unfortunately. still getting the same error as stated in the issue.
